# Select sum of 2 rows with condition per column

Tags: sql, select, sum

```
TotalQty   AmountDiscounted       ReturnDescription
1.0000      12.50                   NULL
1.0000      12.50                   RETURN
1.0000      20.625                  NULL
```

I have a database design like that! What I want to do is to multiply the rows `TotalQty` and `AmountDiscounted` and get them sum..

So far I have a query like this.

`SELECT sum(TotalQty * AmountDiscounted) FROM FinishedSales`

But I'm having a problem when I am working with conditions. I want the `AmountDiscounted` columns to become a negative when the `ReturnDescription` has a value of Return. So basically, the final answer will be 20.625

Comment: can you use a case or decode? select sum(TotalQty * AmountDiscounted * decode(ReturnDescription,'RETURN',-1,1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ReturnDescription = 'Return' THEN - TotalQty * AmountDiscounted
                ELSE TotalQty * AmountDiscounted
           END)
FROM FinishedSales;
```